# Can not get any extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I can not get any online extension (and even list of extensions) from VS 2013 Professional.

> The HTTP request to 'https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/services/dev12/extension.svc' has exceeded the allowed timeout.

But I can open https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/services/dev12/extension.svc in the browser on the same computer.

I have turned off firewall, but it doesn' help.  How can I fix it?

Comment: Same problem here (different error message, though). I guess there's a problem with that update service for VS 2013. VS 2012 (same machine) can still get the list.

Comment: Same problem here. You can go to https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ in your browser to find and download/install extensions until it's fixed.